# History of CP437 character "ñ"

Tags: character-encoding

Does anybody know why letter "ñ" preceeds letter "Ñ" in code page 437?

> ñ -> ALT+164
>
> Ñ -> ALT+165

While for the rest of the characters uppercase precedes lowercase.
Just wondering

Comment: ASCII ends at 127. This is not an ASCII question.

Comment: I think you're probably talking about a DOS or Windows character set - it's certainly not ASCII anyway.

Comment: 'ñ' < 'Ñ' isn't unique.  There's also 'å' < 'Å', 'æ' < 'Æ', 'é' < 'É', 'ö' < 'Ö', and 'ü' < 'Ü'.